# What are supported stream formats for h.265

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, h.265

I wanted to know what are the possible streaming formats for streaming a video using H.265.

Does H.265 support rtsp and rtmp based streaming?

Currently, I am using ffmpeg to live stream the camera feed from my Android phone to the Wowza streaming server.

The following command throws no errors but the streaming does not begin from ffmpeg. I mean the bit rate logs for transfer do not show up.

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - -c -copy -f hevc -vcodec libx265 -f rtsp rtsp://10.31.5.126:1935/app2/myStream
```

Answer (score 1):

That command isn't well-formed. First, you specify copy, then specify a raw HEVC format with HEVC encoding and then RTSP as an output format.

Try

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - -vcodec libx265 -f rtsp rtsp://10.31.5.126:1935/app2/myStream
```

Comment: why did u remove the "hevc" and the -copy part?

Comment: I tried using your command. When I use it I get this output --> http://ideone.com/fAgmuD

Comment: First of all, your ffmpeg build does not have x265 or any other HEVC encoder, so nothing will work. I removed copy since you are ingesting a JPEG sequence and want a HEVC stream, so copy makes no sense. `-f hevc` outputs a raw HEVC stream, which you don't want, but in any case, you are overriding it with a rtsp format flag. But all that is irrelevant. You need ffmpeg with a HEVC encoder like x265.

Comment: ok I got the x265 part. Lets say I replace x265 with x264 for now. Will your command work? In fact I replaced the libx265 with libx264. However the transfer does not start

Comment: The errors you get "Main.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected" and "Main.java:4: error: unclosed character literal" indicate something to do with java, not ffmpeg. Either you are not calling it correctly or some characters need to be escaped or enclosed. Don't know what exactly.

Comment: no no @Mulvya that has nothing to do with code. I just used that website to show you the ffmpeg output. Can you tell why this ffmpeg command that you have given is not working. It does not start streaming. I have replaced libx265 with libx264

Comment: Paste the full console output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37275/discussion-between-parth-doshi-and-mulvya).